# mathematical expression in figure name bookdown

Tags: html, latex, r-markdown, bookdown

Is it posible to add mathematical expressions in figure name on a bookdown document?

````
---
title: "Probabilidad"
output:
  bookdown::html_document2: default
---

here is some useless text

```{r fig.cap="lambda$"}
plot(cars)
```
````

I want to put the lambda greek letter in the `fig.cap=`  field or other more complex latex expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LaTeX math expressions in figure captions, e.g.,

````
---
title: "Probabilidad"
output:
  bookdown::html_document2: default
---

```{r fig.cap="$\\lambda$"}
plot(cars)
```

It doesn't matter how complicated the math expression is:


```{r fig.cap="$\\frac{\\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}$"}
plot(cars)
```
````

[image: Using LaTeX math expressions in figure captions]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
fig.cap="<span>&lambda;</span>"
```

This gives an answer to the lambda problem via html, not sure if that'll be enough to handle the latex expressions you need.

Comment: it works but what about more complex latex expression like \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n} ?